# How can you set a preset name to a file in a library

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, flow

I have made a document libary with a Excel template and a flow behind it. Now when a file is created it is given the name XLS File.xls, but I want it to have a name called Form . How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Create a SharePoint workflow to update the Path and Name property by Update List item action.

[image]